# Problema com foco de janelas

Tags: c#, winforms

Bom dia, estou com problema pra controlar foco em de janelas em algumas situações. Preciso controlar bem isso por uma sempre deve bloquear a outra.

Tenho uma solução com várias janelas, usarei como exemplo as Janelas 1,2,3 e 4.

A 2 é filha da 1, aberta com ShowDialog, a 3 e 4 são filhas da 2 e são parte de uma Biblioteca de Classes que tenho, não estando no mesmo projeto que as telas 3 e 4.

Preciso que sempre que a 3 e 4 se fecharem o foco fique na Janela 2, que é a que as abre, porém está ocorrendo de ao serem fechadas elas darem foco na Janela 1, e estranhamente teclas de atalho funcionam, mesmo estando a janela 2 aberta por ShowDialog(), isso não pode ocorrer.

Imagino que tenha alguma relação por as janelas 3 e 4 serem parte de outro projeto.

Estou trabalhando com C#, WindowsForms

Já tentei bastante coisa, não sei mais como proceder.

Alguém da uma Luz?

Comment: Coloque o código que você tentou para que possamos ajudar-lhe.

Comment: Sem o código não tem como adivinhar, edite sua pergunta apresentando um [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

As telas são manipuladas de uns 15 pontos diferentes, de mateiras diferentes, só perguntei mesmo por que alguém poderia ter alguma ideia.

Mas obrigado, vou fechar a thread.